# Is the JavaScript Number an arbitrary-precision number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, literals, arbitrary-precision

If I write the number literal `1.34` in JavaScript, it tells me its `constructor` is named `Number`. Does JavaScript use [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) with `Number` literals?

Answer (score 2):

Nope! Check out [this MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Numbers) on JavaScript, it states:

> Numbers in JavaScript are **"double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754
>   values"**, according to the spec.

Answer (score 1):

No, but there's a [toFixed method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) you can use to convert a number to a fixed value (string).

Comment: That's true but the string doesn't get you any more precision or range.

Comment: why answer your own question?

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose He probably struggled with this question, and wanted to kindly share the solution with others.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose: I can't tell you why, but it's accepted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question